# an Issue with automake

Tags: c, cygwin, automake

I am running an existing C project, and having an error. It was used to have no problem, and I could not fix it even after reading similar issues and trying their solutions.

```
./autogen.sh
running: aclocal
' is already registered with AC_CONFIG_FILES.
/usr/src/ports/autoconf2.5/autoconf2.5-2.69-3.noarch/src/autoconf2.69/lib/autoconf/status.m4:288: AC_CONFIG_FILES is 
expanded from...
configure.ac:890: the top level
autom4te-2.69: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal-1.15: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
error: while running 'aclocal'
```

As shown, the "autom4te-2.69" is failing, and I did not see any hints about what to do. I am using "Cygwin" on windows 10.

Any idea about how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The single quote at the beginning of the line is peculiar. It suggests that there's a problem with line endings or something. You may need to use some tools to make the output readable. You say it used to work but now it doesn't. What changed? What did you change?  That is likely to be the problem. Since it is an existing project, presumably you have the source tarball. Could you create a new directory and extract the tarball again and build in that directory? Or is the trouble that it was built to use an antique version of the auto tools and it no longer works with the most recent versions?

Comment: `/usr/src/ports/autoconf2.5` is not the location of the cygwin autoconf package. It seems you are mixing packages. See https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/autoconf2.5/autoconf2.5-2.69-3